# How To Train svm with Surf features?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, svm

I want to train a svm model with Surf features.
I used the code below to get surf key points and descriptors.

```
photo = cv2.imread(r'DataSet\L (1).jpg',0)
surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()
kp = surf.detect(photo,None)
```

I've read that I have to use surf's descriptors to train the model but I don't know how to do it

I've also read that the descriptors have to be of the same size.

How to do that?

Comment: google a bit for "Bag of Words"